# mongoose schema with discriminators not saving field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman, discriminator

In my app I work with [mongoose discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html). I have a user form and a company form. Both use 5 of the same fields from a so called Base-scheme. So they both go the same route. But in my company signup the telephone number is not saved in Mongo.

I test my fields on a windows 10 machine with Postman.

[image: postman user signup]
[image: postman company signup, the first 5 fields are exactly the same using the discriminator]

```html
 db.base.find()
 //company
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bafb0e70c6eea3fb8256aa6"), "firstName" : "tina", "lastName" : "tipie", "userName" : "bedrijftichelaar@ziggo.nl", "password" : "$2b$10$E4SlixRfGnnNFpxyeBU7f.En1ptnjmJ4D29.1IOg2elDz0RRLqRgq", "companyName" : "Niek BV", "address" : "Uiterwaardenstraat 14", "postcode" : "1234xx", "companyURL" : "www.niekbv.nl", "kvkNr" : "1234", "Kind" : "Company", "isVerified" : false, "__v" : 0 }

//user
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bafb25d0c6eea3fb8256aa8"), "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "Tichelaar", "userName" : "tichelaarpeter@gmail.com", "telephone" : "06123", "password" : "$2b$10$0vfYrRNETbvn/aBYK3tJBOewKdi44esqWQD/IBFzW23dFxNFYBVVC", "Kind" : "User", "isVerified" : false, "__v" : 0 }
```

This sounds a little DIY but 2 weeks ago my signup controllers were working fine. Anybody an idea?

Comment: Can you please add your schemas?

Comment: I found the answer. I deleted the field 'telephone' in Postman and rewrote a new field with the same name. And now it works again. Everybody thanks for interest..